# Why can we reuse Text object in WordCount example

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

After see the example of Hadoop: WordCount, I cannot understand why we can reuse the Text object instead of create a new one for each write operation "context.write(...)"?

```
public class WordCount { 

 public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

   **private Text word = new Text();**

   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
     while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {

       // set other String in Text object
       **word.set(itr.nextToken());**
       **context.write(word, one);**
    }
}....
```

My question is if there is only one Text object in each map task, after we change it's content by using "word.set(...)", the previous outcome key-value pair will be affected because the key uses the same Text object and it's content is changed now.

Did I miss something? Thanks in advance for correcting me...

Comment: Are you observing the previous key be affected?

Comment: @cricket_007no, this just a question in my head, I want to know why we can code like this.

Comment: Because the object is already serialized and written into a memory buffer. Those bytes aren't manipulated after written, so the object can be reused

Answer (score 0):

Reusing objects is good practice to avoid creating many new objects. Hence, `context.write(word, one)` in the `map()` method populates and reuses the `word` and `one` objects.

[context.write()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/TaskInputOutputContext.html#write(KEYOUT,%20VALUEOUT)) will generate an output key/value pair. The `Hadoop` framework will take care of serializing the data when `context.write()`is called. Hence, you can safely reuse the objects within `map()` method.

Comment: Do you mean `context.write()` will create new object for key-value pair for next processing?

Comment: No, `context.write()` will reuse the existing `word` and `one` objects. The `map()` method will be called once per input record. Now, `word` is an instance of class `Text`, which implements `WritableComparable` improving serialization efficiency. Also, the `word.set(String newValue)` method is used to update the contents of `word` for each call of the `map()` method, allowing the `word` object to be reused during each call.

Comment: For reference, you can look at: (1) https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Mapper and (2) http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#set(java.lang.String).